# Incredibuild add-in fails to build C++ solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, incredibuild

I upgraded my older [Incredibuild](https://www.incredibuild.com) installation with the latest version [10.5](https://docs.incredibuild.com/win/latest/windows/release_notes.html) to fix an invalid license error on Windows and I also upgraded my Visual Studio 2022 add-in respectively since I'm working in Visual Studio on C++ projects. When I initiate a build with Incredibuild, I'm getting a failure the following output:

```
--------------------Build System Warning---------------------------------------
Checking MSBuild version:
    Cannot load version info from: �l�R�ct Visual Studio Solution File, Format VersionMSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\, Error: 123

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------Build System Warning---------------------------------------
Visual Studio does not include an English language pack:
    This version of Visual Studio does not include a built-in English language pack.
    
    For the best Incredibuild experience, it is highly recommended to install a Visual Studio English language pack.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Build ID: {184494E3-2125-4767-B661-F6D0037AE45A}
 
Active code page: 437
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 
2 build system warning(s):
   - Checking MSBuild version
   - Visual Studio does not include an English language pack
```

I verified my Visual Studio Installer language packs and I have English installed, my Visual Studio is in English after all so the warning seems bogus:
[image]

Overall I don't understand why Incredibuild is failing, maybe it calls a bad command in the Visual Studio 2022 development tools which implies a poorly developed software but I cannot verify that easily due to the opaque nature of this commercial tool. I never got Incredibuild to work before, either, but it would be great to accelerate builds. I can build my C++ code just fine in Visual Studio via the regular `Build` -> `Build Solution` menu item, though.

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support? I would guess they've seen this issue before and would be able to help you solve it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Agreed, I sent them an e-mail now but they didn't seem to want to help a lot last time I tried at a company where we had another issue with them...

Comment: One thing I would worry about if you've used older versions is making sure everything that could point to those older versions has been removed completely. It has been a while but I do remember having to do some registry digging to fix something. Their support was mostly helpful for that and other issues at the time but it was several years ago and we were paying them a substantial amount of money so the threat of "If it doesn't work I won't need to pay for it" may have had something to do with that. Good luck! :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Yep, you would think but they lost us as a potential customer since we wanted to try it and it didn't work, nor did they provide a reasonable solution. To be fair, the solution setup at the company was quite unusual with supporting extensions so it's expected to not play nice with all sorts of tools like Incredibuild after all

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the support's suggestion worked fine to fix the build failure. Here's the solution:

1. On your machine, in the Window Search, type in Region
2. A window should appear, go to the Administrative tab
3. A Region Settings window will pop up, ensure the Current system locale is English (United States), and the checkbox is uncheck for 'Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support'. See screenshot below as reference.
4. You can try a build to see if this takes away the messages, but a machine restart may be needed after making any changes.

[image]